# TextView setEllipsize with text that have whitespaces

Tags: android-layout

I'm using a TextView element with following layout settings

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:maxLines="1" android:lines="1" 
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="AAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"/>
```

As you can see I'm trying to add triple dot to the end of the long text, but for some reason all it does with texts that contain whitespaces is to cut the phrase without putting any dots in the end. Is there any workaround for this issue ?

Thanks.

UPD:it actually drops everything after the whitespace on the next line. This is strange regarding the fact that android:maxLines="1" android:lines="1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the attribute: `android:singleLine="true"`.

You can remove your `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:lines="1"` attributes afterwards.